# Can I refer to ruby parameters by index?

Tags: ruby, closures

In swift it is possible to omit the list of parameters in a closure and refer to each of them using its index (`$0, $1, $2...`)

Can the same approach being used with Ruby?
It would make some code easier to read

```
# current syntax
myArray.map { | item | item * 2 } 

# as it could be
myArray.map { $0 * 2 }
```

Comment: Wow. I like this syntax. You should open a feature request for Ruby. This is a great idea. But sadly this does not currently work for Ruby.

Comment: This exact feature request already exists and was shot down for the obvious reason: it would break massive amounts of code, since `$1`, `$2`, etc. already have a completely different meaning and are often used in blocks (in the block form of `String#gsub`).

Comment: thanks @JörgWMittag! Do you have the link for that feature request? I'm curious to check if someone proposed a different syntax to solve the problem with the regexp.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can access them as an array, but it's not really the same thing:

```
my_array.map { |*_| _[0] * 2 }
```

The only option along these lines that Ruby offers is the `&:` syntax, which you can use for the special case of calling a method on the first parameter:

```
my_array.map(&:succ)

# is equivalent to:

my_array.map { |item| item.succ }
```